# Using map to format JSON

Tags: ruby, dashing

I'm somewhat new to Ruby and I'm working on a dashboard application using Dashing.io and I have some JSON data that, after doing `JSON.parse` on it, currently looks like this:

```
{"location"=>"Madison Central", "Members"=>{"Mike"=>"Minecraft crafting", "Dave"=>"3D printing"}}
```

What I need to do now is to map the content in `"Members"` so that it looks like the following:

```
{:label => "Mike", :value=> "Minecraft crafting"}
{:label => "Dave", :value=> "3D printing"}
```

I tried using `map` as follows:

```
event_data = response.map{|who,status| {label: who, value: status} }
```

but it outputs (predictably) wrongly:

```
{:label=>"location", :value=>"Madison Central"}
{:label=>"Members", :value=>{"Mike"=>"Minecraft crafting", "Dave"=>"3D printing"}}
```

How to I get to just what I need in the "Members" array in the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pull the `"Members"` out of the hash first

```
event_data = response["Members"].map{ |who, status| {label: who, value: status }}
```

Comment: That was perfect thanks! Just missing a closing `}` ;)